# Alternative method of listHarmfulApps() in play integrity API

Tags: android, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api, safetynet-api

We are using [listHarmfulApps()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient#public-tasksafetynetapi.harmfulappsresponse-listharmfulapps) method from SafetyNet API to get list of harmful app install on user device. As we are migrating to play integrity API.

1. What is the alternative of this method in play integrity API to get info about harmful app installed?
2. is that alternative method in play integrity API return as a list of app (just like  SafetyNet API)?
3. As per deprication [timeline](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/safetynet/deprecation-timeline), Starting January 2024, will only the SafetyNet Attestation feature return an error, or will the entire SafetyNet API, including the listHarmfulApps() method, return an error? FYI: we have already migrated to using the Play Integrity API for attestation.

Answer (score 0):

Todd, from Android/Play here -

**What is the alternative of this method in play integrity API to get info about harmful app installed?**

We are now recommending for devs to use PIA to get the Play Protect status vs using the old SafetyNet API. One difference to note however is that PIA is not providing the actual list of harmful apps, this is a deliberate choice to preserve privacy.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdicts#environment-details-field

**Is that alternative method in play integrity API return as a list of app (just like SafetyNet API)?**

It doesn't return the list of apps and instead confirms if harmful apps are installed on the device.

**As per deprication timeline, Starting January 2024, will only the SafetyNet Attestation feature return an error, or will the entire SafetyNet API, including the listHarmfulApps() method, return an error? FYI: we have already migrated to using the Play Integrity API for attestation.**

Just the Attestation API.

Jan 2024 - If you have migrated to the Play Integrity API, SafetyNet Attestation will continue to work on the former versions of your app. You can still detect risky interactions with the previous versions of your app. If you have not migrated, SafetyNet Attestation will no longer work for your app (including the previous versions) and return an error. We will consider that you have migrated if your app calls the Play Integrity API in production.

January 2025 - SafetyNet Attestation will no longer work for any version of your app. Your app will receive an error.

The migration timeline is provided here - https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/safetynet/deprecation-timeline#safetynet_attestation_deprecation_timeline